# How can I loop in polymorphic relation by passing query reference?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I dont know if its called query reference. Feel free to make edits.

I have a `polymorphic` relation on my `Article Model`:

```
public function comments(){

        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');

    }
```

Now I have to send a  `polymorphic` relation data to my view.

```
public function show(Article $article)
    {

        return view('article.show',[
            'article' => $article,
            'comments' => $article->comments()
        ]);
    }
```

I'm sending it by `$article->comments()` because I want to use each `comments` eloquent relations.

On my blade:

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
                {{dd($comment)}} //This won't execute. What is wrong?
@endforeach
```

if I `dd(comments)` before `foreach` I've this: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute the query ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties)):

```php
public function show(Article $article)
{

    return view('article.show',[
        'article' => $article,
        'comments' => $article->comments
                                        ^^
    ]);
}
```

Comment: yes I can do that.. but I cannot use the relations that I have on my `Comment` model. I'll only get the article comments data

Comment: Oh I'm an idiot... how I can differentiate $article->comments() and $article->comments .... sometime both work ..

Comment: They always return different results. `$article->comments` and `$article->comments()->get()` are equivalent, do you mean that?